# Why is Django ORM explain() function not giving expected output?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to understand how the `.explain()` function works in **Django ORM**.

The official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#explain) says this.

```
print(Blog.objects.filter(title='My Blog').explain())
```

gives below output.

> Seq Scan on blog  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=10 width=12)   Filter: (title
>
> = 'My Blog'::bpchar)

But if I try to print the same thing in my local **Django shell**, it is giving me different output like below.

```
print(OCUser.objects.all().explain())
```

gives

> SIMPLE alyssa_ocuser None ALL None None None None 2853 100.0 None

which is not similar to the one in the official documentation.

I'm not sure what this **SIMPLE**, and all those **None** values are. Can someone please explain?

When I filter the query, I'm getting as below.

```
print(OCUser.objects.filter(chain_code=110).explain(format='text'))
```

> 1 SIMPLE alyssa_ocuser None ALL None None None None 2853 10.0 Using
>   where

Am I doing something wrong?

```
Python: 3.7.3
Django: 2.1.5
Mysql: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26
```

Comment: No this is the expected output. It is in essence the formatting you get when you would write `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM alyssa_ocuser;`. If you filter, then evidently the query plan is different.

Comment: The documentation on the other hand, deals with a PostgreSQL database, as is specified.

Comment: Updated the question with Filtered query result. May I know what those None values in Output are?

Comment: :P these are the `partitions`, `possible_keys`, `key`, `key_len` and `ref`. These are the columns of the `EXPLAIN` result.

Comment: Ok ok. Now I got it. Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `explain()` literally translates to raw SQL `EXPLAIN` which is specific to the Database we are using.

In the official documentation, they've used Postgres where as I was using MySQL DB.

I got the output specific to MySQL which is same as `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, you can get the more readable result (i.e. including column headers for the `EXPLAIN` output) with some extra work: get the raw SQL for the query, then prefix that with `EXPLAIN` in a MySQL session.

E.g.

```
>>> from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
>>> qs = LogEntry.objects.order_by("action_time")                                                                                                                   
>>> qs.query.sql_with_params()                                                                                                                                      
('SELECT `django_admin_log`.`id`, `django_admin_log`.`action_time`, `django_admin_log`.`user_id`, `django_admin_log`.`content_type_id`, `django_admin_log`.`object_id`, `django_admin_log`.`object_repr`, `django_admin_log`.`action_flag`, `django_admin_log`.`change_message` FROM `django_admin_log` ORDER BY `django_admin_log`.`action_time` ASC', ())

$ ./manage.py dbshell
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `django_admin_log`.`id`, `django_admin_log`.`action_time`, `django_admin_log`.`user_id`, `django_admin_log`.`content_type_id`, `django_admin_log`.`object_id`, `django_admin_log`.`object_repr`, `django_admin_log`.`action_flag`, `django_admin_log`.`change_message` FROM `django_admin_log` ORDER BY `django_admin_log`.`action_time` ASC;

+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table            | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | django_admin_log | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   19 |   100.00 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```